# How to use custom fonts in @react-pdf/pdfkit

Tags: reactjs, pdfkit, react-pdf

Can anyone say how to **add custom fonts and use it** with [@react-pdf/pdfkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-pdf/pdfkit) in React.js.
I tried to register custom font like this.

```
import utils from "./utils";
const SVGtoPDF = require("svg-to-pdfkit");
const PDFDocument = require("@react-pdf/pdfkit").default;
const { Base64Encode } = require("base64-stream");

const generatePDF = async (width, height, canvas, fonts) => {
  const canvasSvg = canvas.toSVG();
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      var doc = new PDFDocument({
        bufferPages: true,
        size: [width * 0.75, height * 0.75],
      });

      utils.getFont(fonts).forEach(async (font) => {
        doc.registerFont(font.family, font.path, font.family);
      });
      
      doc.font("Pacifico").text("Hello Message");
      
      let finalString = "";
      const stream = doc.pipe(new Base64Encode());
      SVGtoPDF(doc, canvasSvg, 0, 0);
      stream.on("data", (chunk) => (finalString += chunk));
      stream.on("end", () => {
        resolve(finalString);
      });
      doc.end();
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
};

export default generatePDF;
```

`getFont()` function will return an array of objects having props like

```
{
  path: "@fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf",
  family: "Pacifico",
  weight: "regular",
  style: "normal",
  }
```

I have added @font as alias to the path where I have saved the .ttf fonts.
So technically, the following is happening

```
doc.registerFont("Pacifico", "src/fonts/Pacifico-Regural.ttf");
```

And I tried to use the font like this:

```
doc.font("Pacifico").text("Hello Message");
```

But I got the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): fontkit.openSync unavailable for browser build
```

Is there is any other method to add font and use it in react-pdf/pdfkit?

Comment: Can you provide more code - how you created document and how you piped document to blob?

Comment: @StefanZivkovic , I have added the complete code. The pdf is generating successfully if I am not adding the font.